# How to load the menu in Nebular Angular 6 from the different component?

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular. I have created the skeleton module and I am having the skeleton.html, .ts, .css files. I am trying to load the skeleton.component from the app.component.html file using router.

I am having the menu in the `skeleton` component but it is not fitting at the correct position.

> app.component.html

```
<nb-layout>
    <nb-layout-header fixed>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <h3>Working</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div>
                <a routerLink="/home" class="nb-home"></a>
                <a (click)="goBack()" class="nb-arrow-left"></a>
                <nb-search class="search" type="rotate-layout"></nb-search>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </nb-layout-header>
    <nb-layout-column>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </nb-layout-column>
</nb-layout>
```

`skeleton.component.html`

```
<nb-sidebar >
    <nb-menu [items]="items">
    </nb-menu>
</nb-sidebar>
<nb-layout-column>
        <!--router-outlet></router-outlet-->
</nb-layout-column>
```

And I am having the all other components which are related to the `skeleton` modules. I am trying to load that components into the skeleton component inside the `<nb-layout-column>`. But it is rendering the other component but the side menu is disappearing.

> skeletonchild.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"  *ngFor="let x of imgObj; index as i;">
            <nb-card>
                    <nb-card-header>{{x['title']}}</nb-card-header>
            <nb-card-body class="regss">
                <div class="content" >{{x['content']}}</div>

                <img class="imgs" [src]="x['url']" alt="x['alt']" >

            </nb-card-body>
        </nb-card>
    </div>

</div>
```

Can you guys tell me what is going wrong in my code.?

Comment: We'll need full reprouction. The main missing part are your route definitions. This has hardly anything to do with templates.